# Print nested complicated object

Tags: javascript, json, nested

I have objects. They are nested and I actually don't know what the parameters are contained in the object.
For example, it can be

```
{
  "option1": "value1",
  "option2": "value2",
  "option3": {
    "suboption1": "subvalue1",
    "suboption2": {
       "subsuboption1": "subsubvalue1"
    }
  },
  "option4": "value4"
}
```

I need to print this object like:

```
<span class="depth-0"><b>option1</b>: value1</span>
<span class="depth-0"><b>option2</b>: value2</span>
<span class="depth-0"><b>option3</b>:</span>
<span class="depth-1"><b>suboption1</b>: subvalue1</span>
<span class="depth-1"><b>suboption2</b>:</span>
<span class="depth-2"><b>subsuboption1</b>: subsubvalue1</span>
<span class="depth-0"><b>option4</b>: value4</span>
```

It looks like a simple task but I have a big problem with indents on the depth. Maybe someone has the similar problem.
I use javascript and lodash lib in my project.
I need some function in my template.

Comment: you want to do this with javascript ?

Comment: yes. i need some function in my template. and i use lodash in my project, if it can help.

Comment: Have you attempted anything in terms of an implementation?

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), giving the `space` paramater `"--"` or a tab depending on how you want it:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({
  "option1": "value1","option2": "value2",
  "option3": {
    "suboption1": "subvalue1",
    "suboption2": {
       "subsuboption1": "subsubvalue1"
    }
  },
  "option4": "value4"
}, null, '--'));
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but apart from the usual indent I need to use some html tags for keys and values and I'm not sure that JSON.stringify allows to do it

Comment: @Anastasiia You can use `.outerHTML` to change your elements to a string of HTML for displaying.

Comment: I updated my question that now you can see why I can't use it

Answer (score 1):

You can try following

```js
var object = {
  "option1": "value1",
  "option2": "value2",
  "option3": {
    "suboption1": "subvalue1",
    "suboption2": {
      "subsuboption3": "subsubvalue3"
    }
  },
  "option4": "value4"
};




function paint(obj, level) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      console.log('<span class="depth-"' + level +'><b>'+key + '</b>: </span>');
      paint(obj[key], level + 1);
    } else {
      console.log('<span class="depth-"' + level + '><b>'+key + '</b>: '+ obj[key]+'</span>');

    }
  }
}


paint(object, 0);
```

Comment: I tried to use it and understood that i can't. I update a question that you can see why.

Comment: @Anastasiia - I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: @Anastasiia - Did you tried? Also, in place of console.log you can append that as html